# find all elements in a dictionary satisfying a criteria

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary

d = {'foo' : 10 , 'bar' : 12 , 'asd' : 4}

I want to find all keys that have corresponding value less than or equal to 10, and their locations in the dictionary. So the expected output is

{'foo', 'asd'} for keys , and [1 3] for the locations

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: python dict is not ordered. so your question makes no sense. You can get the keys but not the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost same as @Chitoge's solution,

but in order to match your expected output, here is my solution

```
d={'foo': 10,'bar': 12,'asd': 4}
key_list = []
key_index = []
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    if v<=10: 
        key_list.append(k)
        key_index.append(d.keys().index(k) + 1)

print key_list
print key_index
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate through the dictionary with `iteritems()`

```
d={'foo': 10,'bar': 12,'asd': 4}

for _,v in d.iteritems():
    if v<=10: print v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'foo' : 10 , 'bar' : 12 , 'asd' : 4}
>>> [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v <=10]
['foo', 'asd']
```

Location will change every time since the dictionary is not ordered.